# Antenna connection 3G modems

Tags: 3g, modem

something less software related. :)

I need to identify the antenna connector for two of 3g modems. the connector looks like this:
[image: modem]

I do have a crc9 antenna i would like to use, so i just have to find something like an adapter or so.

Problem, I live in tanzania where something like this is usually not available

best regards
and thanks

michael

Comment: First, this is off-topic here, please see the [FAQ]. Also, I edited out the second image because the watermark clearly indicates the creator of this picture does not agree to use it elsewhere.

Comment: I checked on stackexchange if there is anywhere else where it would probably be more related than in serverfault, but there isn't anything and actually I'm building a fallback internet connection for a hiv and tb research institute in tanzania east africa, after the last big cut out fín egypt. I am the system administrator, sorry if this is not serverfault related enough

Comment: This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an **extraordinarily narrow situation** that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ. http://serverfault.com/faq#close

Comment: @MeikoWatu: First, I still think it's off-topic as it boils down to shopping, regardless the purpose. Second: No one has the ability to cast more than one downvote on a question, which just means that *two* people voted on your question. So, please before you throw around accusations, learn how the site works.

Comment: @Meiko Watu: It is this http://routerz.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/DSC_1269.jpg ? There is no connector name but better photo.

Comment: @SvenW sorry, but i don't see the difference here in between asking where a specific error message comes from and what a specific connector does, how is this related to shopping? If there would be any easy to find answer on the internet i would probably have found it and not to ask the question. I know that 3g questions are rare here, but that doesn't mean everything is unrelated is it? and deleting comments is for helping to improve the question. whoever did it. it kinda reminds me of some german it news forum here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It look like diagnostc connector. Then to use it as external antenna connector you possibly must cut internal antenna. After this modification it can't work without external antenna.
2. Think about reflector (usually grid antenna) antenna where you install modem itself in antenna focus. Like this - http://www.clearchain.com/blog/posts/improving-3g-mobile-broadband-reception-without-an-antenna It work with any modem. **In this case You don't need to modify modem.** Only restriction is usb cable length. But using long antenna cable also not good (mostly bad).

Comment: thanks @mmv-ru i'll look it up and probably cut the internal antenna. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a U.FL connectors - they're commonly seen on embedded wi-fi cards in laptops etc. If it were me, I'd be looking to take an internal antenna out of a laptop with the connector intact, and then modifying it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPX_connector

[image: U.FL Connector]

Comment: I sure it not u.FL connector.

Comment: uFL followed by MMCX are the most common internal connectors by far (especially the former). RP-SMA and N are the most common external connections (for consumer and professional equipment respectively).

Comment: @mmv-ru Why'd you say that, looks similar in size and profile to me. I think MMCX would be too tall to sit internally, unless it's actually designed to take an external antenna.

Comment: thanks! I'll look up which exact port it is and try to cut out the internal antenna on an old stick. hopefully it'll help us to have a reliable backup internet connection

Comment: @Dan Maybe it misunderstood. Really on Your good photo is u.FL connector. I say about original Meiko Watu photo, there is not the u.FL.